# Netty 4.x client file upload

Tags: http, netty

I've written an Http client around the new netty 4.0 lib.
I can't seem to find where/how a post request should include files.
One use case I've found now is uploading photos to a third party API.

The DefaultHttpRequest class has setContent for a buffer to be passed in
but is there any utility to encode the post parameters (inc file fields)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Post support is not yet ported to netty 4. It's on the to-do-list atm..

Comment: Is there a discussion somewhere already about how this is going to be done? I'm going to need it soon so I'd make an attempt at porting it to the new API.

Comment: No not really.. its just that the whole multipart package would need to get ported to the new api

Comment: Okay. There used to be a client file upload example before the move from the org.jboss namespace. Where has that gone? I want to have a look at how the multipart package was used previously and I'll have a go at porting over the next week or so.